# Display time for one value in flot graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

How to force flot chart to display time on xaxis for one value

```
 [1354586000000, 10]
```

with setings:

```
mode: "time",
timeformat: "%b %d",
tickSize: [7, "day"]
```

My example: http://jsfiddle.net/AUrfY/10/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to make your `tickSize` be set to `undefined` in the case where there is only 1 value.

Here's the relevant bit:

```
var tickSize = [7,'day'];
if (data7_1.length == 1 && data7_2.length == 1){
   tickSize = undefined;
}
```

And then in the options, `tickSize:tickSize`.

I made a working version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AUrfY/11/

Comment: That's second time you are helping me with flotchart :) Thank you!